# Mounting TV with plywood backing

Tags: mounting, plywood, television

I am trying to mount my Tv and I am using a 1/2” piece of plywood to make it centered. The TV weighs 78 pounds and not 100% sure about the mount. The mount is a full tilt extension and extends up 5.2”

My question is, can I use a toggle bolt behind the piece of plywood and put the screw from the toggle through plywood to hold the TV bracket secure? I am currently planning on using a 3/4” round slotted screw to hold the bracket to the plywood. I just feel like it won’t be secure enough.

If the toggle idea is not a good solution, then what would be?

Comment: I don't understand your plan. Why would the toggler be _behind_ the plywood? To what are you attaching it? Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: Slotted screws wouldn't be the right option, in my opinion. They can be difficult to get tight without stripping out. I don't even use Phillips head screws if I can avoid it because the driver cams out too easily. Use lag bolts with a hex head that you can put a socket or combination wrench on or use a Torx™/star head screw, square/Robertson or similar.

Answer (score 3):

1/2" is a bit thin, but if the TV isn't too heavy and the mount is not one that pulls way out and applies a lot of leverage to the mount, it might be OK.

Your best bet if you can plan ahead is to use "Tee nuts" and machine screws, the trick being that you have to figure out where you want the TV mount holes and THEN mount the plywood to the wall, not the other way around, as the Tee nuts go into the back of the plywood in the pre-drilled holes to fit the mount pattern.

Comment: @Rob1313 if you purchased a full 4x8 sheet, you can cut another piece and double it up making it 1" thick. The extra thickness won't hurt at all and will only help.